# How to fetch the value from the Json based on Named key in kusto query(KQL) language

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a json field in log analytics workspace and structure looks something like below

```
{
"AdditionalDetails": [
    {
        "value": "SomeValue",
        "key": "SomeKey"
    },
    {
        "value": "SomeValue",
        "key": "SomeKey"
    },
    {
        "value": "somevalue",
        "key": "somekey"
    },
    {
        "value": "SomeTicketNumber",
        "key": "TicketNumber"
    },
    {
        "value": "1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM",
        "key": "ExpirationTime"
    }
]
```

}
I am using Kusto query to filter this data based on the key value Ticket number. Once I remove all other columns I have find out the actual ticket number captured in the value.

I have tried mvexpand, mv-expand and I get something like below.

```
print d = dynamic ({
    "AdditionalDetails": [
        {
            "value": "SomeValue",
            "key": "SomeKey"
        },
        {
            "value": "SomeValue",
            "key": "SomeKey"
        },
        {
            "value": "somevalue",
            "key": "somekey"
        },
        {
            "value": "SomeTicketNumber",
            "key": "TicketNumber"
        },
        {
            "value": "1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM",
            "key": "ExpirationTime"
        }
    ]
})
| project details = d.['AdditionalDetails'] 
| mvexpand details
| project  ticketnumber = details
```

Output

```
{"value":"SomeValue","key":"SomeKey"}
{"value":"SomeValue","key":"SomeKey"}
{"value":"somevalue","key":"somekey"}
{"value":"SomeTicketNumber","key":"TicketNumber"}
{"value":"1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM","key":"ExpirationTime"}
```

requirement is to get only row where the key name is ticketnumber, once i have the row I should be able to project ticket number as column, any suggestion?

*Note : I was able to get the value of the ticket based on the index but Json structure is dynamic so I can't hardcode the index.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `mv-apply`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({
        "AdditionalDetails":[
            {"value":"SomeValue","key":"SomeKey"},
            {"value":"SomeValue","key":"SomeKey"},
            {"value":"somevalue","key":"somekey"},
            {"value":"SomeTicketNumber","key":"TicketNumber"},
            {"value":"2/2/0002 7:00:00 AM","key":"ExpirationTime"}
        ]
    }),
    dynamic({
        "AdditionalDetails":[
            {"value":"AnotherTicketNumber","key":"TicketNumber"},
            {"value":"SomeValue","key":"SomeKey"},
            {"value":"1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM","key":"ExpirationTime"},
            {"value":"SomeValue","key":"SomeKey"},
            {"value":"somevalue","key":"somekey"}
        ]
    }),
]
| mv-apply ad = d.AdditionalDetails on (
    where ad.key == "TicketNumber"
    | project value = tostring(ad.value)
)
| project value
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this perhaps?

[link to execute](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8WSPQvCMBCG9/6Ko5OCH%20niIHQQdBJdFBcRic2hsU1b0lgr6n/3GvD7A3QxZLjwvHnvjrtUy9iAAB/ELuZKBlDZO0DH7QghjUxiHnXRcBllbhumFpVnf4msOOfRBkngjhKFE/uo3StC3J15n8ILPNb%204pnRn/yDZ8nDH%20ocyyBEM9yoBeo31neSb/y9ptdkjHnQajNGFzqDNyl6RSo1L6c3lgpvktho5hyrzgFSnawxoOE3nkZNVOV1LFIeCxDzVxwLgwQpYbk7z5IGEZJtV6jRqsD3H3u/1mB7JCOTZIY2cll55WhF1RMmWi5wsgIAAA==)

```
print d = dynamic ({
    "AdditionalDetails": [
        {
            "value": "SomeValue",
            "key": "SomeKey"
        },
        {
            "value": "SomeValue",
            "key": "SomeKey"
        },
        {
            "value": "somevalue",
            "key": "somekey"
        },
        {
            "value": "SomeTicketNumber",
            "key": "TicketNumber"
        },
        {
            "value": "1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM",
            "key": "ExpirationTime"

        }
    ]
})
| project d.AdditionalDetails
| mv-expand d_AdditionalDetails
| extend key = d_AdditionalDetails.key
| where key  == "TicketNumber"
| project value = tostring(d_AdditionalDetails.value)
```